# AlarmManager opening (Alert)Dialog

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager, android-alertdialog, alarm

My MainActivity sets an Alarm (or multiple Alarms).
When the alarm goes of I want to show an AlertDialog that plays the alarm sound, shows info about the alarm and something like OK and delete, after that it should go back to my MainActivity.

If I read that right I cant create an AlertDialog from the BroadcastReceiver because its not an Activity.

So whats the best way to do this?

Do I have to open an Activity from the Receiver that then opens a Dialog?

EDIT:
I just found out that I probably dont have to use the Receiver, I can just open my Main, get the extras from the Intent and then open the Dialog.

Is there a reason not to it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do need to use an activity to accomplish this. Do something like this:

1. **Use the receiver to start your Main activity.**
2. **Use the Main activity to show an AlertDialog.**

Comment: I just found out that I probably dont have to use the Receiver, I can just open my Main, get the extras from the Intent and then open the Dialog.

Is there a reason not to it like that?

Comment: @TeKo Well, the broadcast receiver is what "receives" the signal from the AlarmManager. Without it, the phone will send a signal that, "something is supposed to happen," but it won't know what. That's what the receiver is for. It "receives" the signal so that you can start an Activity.

As far as using two activities, I misread your question. I updated my answer. You don't need to use 2 activities. You would only need to do that if you wanted to react differently based on whether the user positive clicked or negative clicked the DialogFragment.

Comment: When Im just using the Receiver to start the MainActivity I could just start the MainActivity with the alarm. Then Im getting the extras from the Intetent to show the right Dialog, if there are no extras I do nothing. Seems to work so far. Thanks for the help.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, that should work. You're welcome! Best wishes!